# Using pipes with the python "subprocess" module

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess

Let's say I want to call the program *theprogram* in a windows batch file. The code would look like this :

```
exit | theprogram arg1
```

I've tested it and it works perfectly, many thanks !

Now, big change of strategy, I have to call *theprogram* inside a python script. For this I use the *subprocess* module. I get :

```
subprocess.call(['theprogram', arg1])
```

But for this to work correctly, I need to pipe this with an exit statement, as I did in the batch file. Of course, this **doesn't** work

```
subprocess.call(['exit | theprogram', arg1])
```

Does anyone know how I can correctly pipe this *exit* statement to the input of *theprogram* ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I know this isn't strictly related to this question, but why do you use the ```exit``` command in your batch file?  Why not just ```python theprogram arg1```?

Comment: Yes, please explain why you need to pipe the non-existent output of `exit` into your program. I suspect you would get the same result using `<nul theprogram arg1`

Comment: The program I'd like to execute is in fact sqlplus. When you launches it, it stays open, waiting for an input command until you asks it to exit (by entering the *exit* input). I don't want to enter this *exit* manually every time I launch my python script, I'd rather like it to terminate once it's done, hence the piping :)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `echo exit | sqlplus ...`?

Comment: In the batch file you mean ? No, it works fine without the echo. BTW, pardon me if I'm wrong, but isn't *echo* supposed to be simply prompting stuff on the shell ?

Comment: `echo` is for printing things to standard output. If you want `sqlplus` to receive the string `exit` as its input, you should use `echo exit | sqlplus`. `exit | sqlplus` works because `exit` is essentially a no-op that serves to send end-of-file to `sqlplus` — as correctly remarked by @dbenham.

Comment: Didn't know that (I'm new to batch files and stuff). Thanks for the precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the `shell` keyword argument to parse the invocation through the shell:

```
subprocess.call('exit | theprogram %s' % arg1, shell=True)
```

Of course, this forces you to manually quote `arg1` if it contains whitespace or other shell's metacharacters. Normally it is a feature that `subprocess.call` does not invoke a shell precisely so you needn't worry about quoting issues—but in your case it throws away the baby along with the bathwater because you *want* the shell's help for the pipe operator to work.

A superior alternative that retains the best of both worlds, at the expense of some typing, is to allow the `subprocess` module to set up the pipe:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["exit"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["theprogram", arg1], stdin=p1.stdout)
p1.stdout.close()
p2.communicate()
```

Now you don't need the shell and you don't need to worry about quoting. More examples of the use of the `subprocess` module are available in [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but it addresses a fallacy in your thinking.

You are attempting to instruct sql*plus to EXIT after it finishes running a script. But that is not what your `exit | sqlplus ...` pipe construct is doing. It does not simply pass the `echo` string as input to sqlplus. The pipe takes the output of the `exit` command (there isn't any) and uses it as input for the command on the right.

The proper way to do what you are attempting is to use `echo exit|sqlplus ...`.

The reason your code works is because sqlplus is detecting that there is no further input available (the input buffer is closed), so it immediately quits after executing the script. You would get the same result using any command on the left that does not produce output. For example:

```
(call )|sqlplus ...
```

Another option is to simply redirect input to nul

```
<nul sqlplus ...
```